# Mudar o innerHTML de uma tag

Tags: javascript, html

Eu estou com um pequeno problema, quando vou alterar uma propriedade de qualquer *tag* utilizando o Javascript o *browser* diz:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Mas testei no JSFiddle e funcionou corretamente com os mesmos parâmetros!

Código:

```
function get(idOf) {
    return document.getElementById(idOf);
}

function loadData(id, videoDATA) {
    get(id).src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoDATA;
}

window.onload = function () {
    get('404').innerHtml = '<iframe src="" width="500px" height="400px" frameborder="0" id="frame0"></iframe>';
    loadData('frame0', 'kdWAmMRmELg');
}
```

`<div id="404">...</div>` é uma DIV que eu coloquei caso o `videoDATA` não fosse carregado.

Comment: Teste no JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4tmjjLzk/

Comment: Nenhum erro no JsFiddle que você mandou.

Comment: o que seria <head> no wrap! por isso o jsfiddle não interpretou o erro!

Comment: @Nathan1302 `No wrap - in <head>`, em Portugues: `Em <head>`, quer dizer que o script será colocado dentro do `<head>` no fiddle :)

Answer (score 2):

Esse erro ocorre porque você está tentando alterar o `src` de um elemento que não foi encontrado na página. E ele não foi encontrado porque a linha que *tenta* criá-lo está errada. Você precisa usar `innerHTML` em vez de `innerHtml`:

```
window.onload = function () {
    get('404').innerHTML = '<iframe src="" width="500px" height="400px" frameborder="0" id="frame0"></iframe>';
    loadData('frame0', 'kdWAmMRmELg');
}
```

http://jsbin.com/hipogiwali/1/edit

Comment: +1 pela resposta. Off-topic: O "SandBox" do StackSnippet não permite incluir `<iframe>` para postar um exemplo funcional?

Comment: Não sei, usei o jsbin justamente para evitar problemas de acesso cross-domain. O JSFiddle reclamaria.

Answer (score -1):

Troca `window.onload` por `document.onready`.

Provavelmente no JSFiddle não de erro porque os JavaScripts que são carregados ficam ao final do HTML onde certeza que estão prontos.